# Synchronized release order

Tags: java, synchronized

I scanned all the java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) on the `synchronized` statements looking for an answer to this question with no luck.

Say I have `thread1`, `thread2`, `thread3` trying to run the following code all at the same time.

```
 synchronized(lockObj) { 
     doSomething();
 }
```

Assume `thread1` gets first to `doSomething()`, `thread2` then `thread3` which will block and wait on the `synchronized` statement.

**Question**

1. When `thread1` releases the lock, which of the threads will be released first?
2. What is the general order rule that applies when releasing a lock?

Comment: Why not just use a BlockingQueue such as an [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) or something similar? Or am I not understanding your question.

Comment: I would sum it up in a single term: threads waiting on a monitor are enlisted in a wait [**set**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My confusion actually started after reading this code http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm I have always thought locks where managed in a FIFO way but apparently not

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Either thread2 or thread3. There is no guarantee:

*Likewise, no assumptions should be made about the order in which threads are granted ownership of a monitor or the order in which threads wake in response to the notify or notifyAll method*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/thread-priorities.html#general

2. Java monitors (synchronized/await/notify/notifyAll) are non-fair. The synchronization primitives from java 1.5 usually have parameters to enforce the fairness. Be advised that the fair version have a considerably performance penalty, usually the non-fair version should work be used: statistically, every thread will be given the chance to run, even if the order is not strictly enforced.

*Programs using fair locks accessed by many threads may display lower overall throughput (i.e., are slower; often much slower) than those using the default setting, but have smaller variances in times to obtain locks and guarantee lack of starvation. Note however, that fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of thread scheduling. Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are not progressing and not currently holding the lock. Also note that the untimed tryLock method does not honor the fairness setting. It will succeed if the lock is available even if other threads are waiting.*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock%28boolean%29

Comment: hmm, I knew there were no guarantees with threading, but I always imagined lock queue to be, you know, queue, with fifo and all the stuff. Nice answer.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy The JLS never mentions a queue, but a set. That pretty much says it all.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: perhaps it is because when I took my OS class we were implemeting it as a queue.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy Implementing it as a queue is definitely the more obvious and instructive approach. And keep in mind that I'm only talking at the specification level -- the actual implementations may well be using a queue, but it is important for the JLS not to **guarantee** a queue.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: well, not guaranteeing it makes more room for optimizations and stuff, without making threading any harder. seems like a logical decision.