# Are netty (or java NIO) channels FIFO?

Tags: java, netty, nio, fifo

Are netty channels (or java NIO channels in general) FIFO? or I need to implement FIFO by myself using sequence numbers?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: I mean, if I send a message A, B one after another, do I  receive them on the order side of the channel in order? or I need to check it manually to make sure.

Comment: If you're sending a request on the same TCP socket the server will receive them ordered. It would be good to specify the type of Channel you're using.

Answer (score 2):

NIO maintains a read and write lock internally; however they are implemented using a `synchronized` block in NIO.

There is NO guarantee that Thread B will obtain the lock after Thread A when using `synchronized`.  It is entirely possible that Thread C could obtain write lock before Thread B.

See the following on lock release: [Synchronized release order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275699/synchronized-release-order)

If you NEED guaranteed FIFO across many threads then you need to create a `ReentrantLock` with `fair=true` and require all of your threads to obtain that lock first.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining order is not the responsibility of the transport layer.so your send message A and message B through the same channel(same socket),on the server side the message arrived order is uncertain.

Meet these conditions the message arrived order is send order:

- use TCP protocol
- message A and message B send in one system call

if you need order your application should do it.